# Отправка на telegra.ph посредством curl

Tags: bash, curl, telegram

Есть замечательный сервис **telegra.ph**, как отправлять на него текст посредством curl? Сколько не пытался не получилось

> http://telegra.ph/api#createPage
>
> https://pastebin.com/TEh9J6gQ

Comment: И как отправлять фото вместе с текстом? В упор не вижу в доках словосочетания send image/photo